# fflush behavior change in glibc 2.23

Tags: c, glibc, fflush

As of 2.23 the glibc seems to have changed its behavior on an fflush of a stream created with fmemopen, in that it resets the position to 0.  I saw in the [change-log](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-02/msg00502.html) that a the implementation of fmemopen was updated to fix a bunch of bugs,  but none of those bugs talk about this behavior, and to me it seems like an incorrect change.  I've been trying to determine if this a new bug, or a correct fix.  My own code relies on the old behavior and broke after I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 which comes with glibc 2.23.  Anybody know anything about this?

Here's some sample code:

```
char buffer[500] = "x";
FILE *stream;
stream = fmemopen(buffer, 500, "r+");

fwrite("fish",sizeof(char),5,stream);
printf("pos-1:%ld\n",ftell(stream));
fflush(stream);
printf("pos-2:%ld\n",ftell(stream));
```

On earlier versions (e.g. under ubuntu 5.10<) this would result in:

```
pos-1:5
pos-2:5
```

Now it returns:

```
pos-1:5
pos-2:0
```

Comment: This sure looks like a regression to me, and a pretty serious one.  `fflush()` should not cause the file position to revert to 0.  And such a change *certainly* should not escape mention in the release notes if it is in fact intentional.  I am currently running a much older glibc, but I confirm that it behaves as you describe older glibc to do.  I would file a bug report if there isn't one already.

Comment: Yah, it seems like a big issue to me too.  Currently I'm on IRC#glibc talking with some of the maintainers there to confirm that it's a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in 2.23.  The bug [was logged](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20005) and has been fixed.